# Laravel 8 - Folders created for a new file are created with private permissions

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems, laravel-8

I have a issue with File Storage of Laravel

We want to store a new file in the storage folder in a path that has folders that do not exist at the time of file creation. But the folders will be created with private permissions and not public permissions like the file. This will render the file inaccessible.

In my controller, i use putFileAS

```
// Manually specify a filename...
Storage::putFileAs($path, $file, $nameFile);
```

And in fileststems file

```
'as400' => [
            'driver' => 'sftp',
            'host' => 'xxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx',
            //'port' => 21,
            'username' => 'XXXXXX',
            'password' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            //'privateKey' => 'path/to/or/contents/of/privatekey',
            'root' => '/',
            //'timeout' => 10,
        ],
```

I try to add this

```
Storage::putFileAs(
    $path, 
    $file, 
    $fileName,
    [
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'directory_visibility' => 'public'
    ]
);
```

Or

```
'as400' => [
            'driver' => 'sftp',
            'host' => 'xxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx',
            //'port' => 21,
            'username' => 'XXXXXX',
            'password' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            //'privateKey' => 'path/to/or/contents/of/privatekey',
            'root' => '/',
            //'timeout' => 10,
            'permissions' => [
                'file' => [
                    'public' => 0644,
                    'private' => 0600,
                ],
                'dir' => [
                    'public' => 0755,
                    'private' => 0700,
                ],
             ],
        ],
```

But it's doesn't work. If someone have a solution, I will be grateful !

Comment: Storage::disk('as400')->putFileAs(
    $path, 
    $file, 
    $fileName,
    [
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'directory_visibility' => 'public'
    ]
);

Comment: I've already tried, and it doesn't work